# CMake fails to find QtCore library when crosscompiling

Tags: android, qt, cmake

I'm trying to compile Qt project using android ndk and CMake toolchain from [android-cmake project](http://code.google.com/p/android-cmake/).
In order to make cmake find Qt i've specified -DQMAKE_EXECUTABLE=/path/to/necessitas/qmake
When I run cmake, I get the following:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/pac/build/android.toolchain.cmake ../qMap3D -DANDROID_NDK=/home/vvs/necessitas/android-ndk-r6b -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=/home/vvs/necessitas/Android/Qt/480/armeabi-v7a/bin/qmake -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
Warning: QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE reported QT_INSTALL_LIBS as /home/vvs/necessitas/Android/Qt/480/armeabi-v7a/lib
Warning: But QtCore couldn't be found.  Qt must NOT be installed correctly, or it wasn't found for cross compiling.
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:602 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find QtCore.  Check
  /home/vvs/pac/build-android-cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log for more
  details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The directory $/home/vvs/necessitas/Android/Qt/480/armeabi-v7a/lib does contains libQtCore.so.4.8.0 and a set of symlinks.

Comment: Ok I've got it. It was CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH variable set by android-cmake toolchain.

Comment: Try `find_host_package` instead.